# A variant of the elliptope relaxation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Given a p.s.d. matrix $A$, one may want to find:
$$
\max_x x^t A x \mbox{ such that } x \mbox{ has entries }1 \mbox{ or } {-1}.
$$
This hard problem has a well known relaxation based on the so called elliptope:
$$
\max_C \mbox{trace }CA \mbox{ such that } C \mbox{ is p.s.d. and has its diagonal entries equal to }1.
$$
This relaxation is polynomial time solvable and approximates the initial problem up to a constant factor (this fact is equivalent to the little Grothendieck theorem).

The question is whether a similar relaxation exists for the problem:

$$
\max_{x,y} x^t A y \mbox{ such that } x \mbox{ and } y \mbox{ have entries } 1 \mbox{ or } {-1}.
$$

Here $A$ is a general square matrix.

Comment: Define z=[x;y] and B=[0,A;A',0]. Then you're problem is maximizing z'Bz subject to z having entries in {+1,-1}. You can relax to the elliptope from there.

Comment: oh right, thanks!

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon actually your B is symmetric but not necessarily positive, is it still ok?

Comment: yep, the relaxation is on zz', not B.

Comment: If you want psd for some reason, you can add a large multiple of the identity to B. This just adds a constant to the objective function, so it doesn't change the maximizer.

Comment: Are you sure this is related to functional analysis?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - yes, see e.g. Sect 22 of https://www.math.tamu.edu/~pisier/grothendieck.UNCUT.pdf